# Angular Como parsear una peticion http a un objeto

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo una **peticion http** a mi api en la que  que me devuelve una lista de **objetos** de la siguiente forma:

```
this.usuarioService.getAll().subscribe(
  usuarios => {
  console.log("USUARIOS = ",usuarios);
});
```

He intentado esto :

```
this.usuarioService.getAll().subscribe(
  usuarios => {
  console.log("USUARIOS = ",usuarios);
  this.lista_usuario = JSON.parse(usuarios);
});
```

pero no me lo parsea, este **error** me da:

```
ERROR in src/app/listar-usuarios/listar-usuarios.component.ts(43,39): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Este es el **servicio** que con el que uso las peticiones **http**:

```
  getAll() {
   return this.http.get(this.url+'/all').pipe(map(res =>   res));
  }
```

En definitiva, quiero parsear las peticiones http al objeto en cuestion para no ir haciendo parseos innecesarios y tambien, obviamente, buscar la forma correcta de parsearlos porque no lo consigo solucionar.

Decir que las peticiones me devuelven correctamente los datos, pero los quiero devolver ya como el objeto **Usuario** que esto usando en las paginas de mi app.

---

La vista seria algo como :

```
<tr *ngFor="let usuario of lista_usuarios;let i = index">
  <td>{{usuario.nombre}}</td>
  <td>{{usuario.apel_1}}</td>
  <td>{{usuario.apel_2}}</td>
  <td>{{usuario.email}}</td>
  <td>{{usuario.fecha_nacimiento}}</td>
  <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</a></td>
</tr>
```

Pero me sigue dando error :

```
ERROR Error: "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"
    Angular 7
    View_ListarUsuariosComponent_0 ListarUsuariosComponent.html:26
    Angular 24
    RxJS 5
    Angular 9
ListarUsuariosComponent.html:26:8
ERROR CONTEXT 
Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 34, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} }
ListarUsuariosComponent.html:26:8
    View_ListarUsuariosComponent_0 ListarUsuariosComponent.html:26
    Angular 16
    RxJS 5
    Angular 9

    emit

    checkStable

    onLeave

    onInvokeTask

    invokeTask

    runTask

    invokeTask

    invokeTask

    globalZoneAwareCallback
```

El `subscribe` de usuarios me da el **json()** pero al almacenarlo en el array y luego hace un `console.log()` del array me sale **vacio**

Comment: ¿La propiedad `this.http` es una instancia de  HttpClient? En ese caso ya está parseado, por eso te falla

Comment: En algun punto de tu componente tienes esto `lista_usuario: string` en lugar de `lista_usuario: any` o el tipo que le toque ser o tu `this.url` es de tipo object y no string como piensas.

Comment: Si, es de HttpClient, o sea que te viene parseado. Y como se lo asigno a un  objeto como este =  `lista_usuario = new Array<Usuario>();`
`

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, si esta parseado deberia poder hacer esto = `this.lista_usuario =  usuarios;`

Comment: Tras la actualización: la respuesta no es un array. Mira bien qué te devuelve tu backend, porque parece un objeto normal. Quizá este objeto contenga el array que buscas

Comment: Si parece ser un `Array` , esto es el `console.log()` `usuarios: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]`

Comment: Por cierto, lo estoy intentando almacenar en un array como este =      `public lista_usuarios= [];`

Answer (score 1):

Angular, desde la versión 5, hace el parseo automáticamente según el content-type de la respuesta, con lo que así ya debería funcionar:

```
this.usuarioService.getAll().subscribe(
  usuarios => {
  console.log("USUARIOS = ",usuarios);
  this.lista_usuario = usuarios; //sin parse, usuarios ya debería ser un array de usuarios
});
```

En el servicio es innecesario llamar a pipe porque no realizas nada con la respuesta:

```
 getAll() : Observable<Usuarios[]> {
   return this.http.get<Usuarios[]>(this.url+'/all');
 }
```

Comment: Eso pensaba yo, pero me arroja el siguiente error `ERROR in src/app/listar-usuarios/listar-usuarios.component.ts(46,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Usuario[]>' is not assignable to type 'Usuario[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<Usuario[]>'.`

Comment: Lo he escrito sin fijarme demasiado... creo que ahora debería estar bien

Comment: no me lo hace aun, estoy probando unas cosas

Comment: console.log de usuarios me devuelve el json, pero luego hago un console.log a lista_usuarios() y no hay nada. De hecho al cargar la pagina me da el siguiente error:

Comment: `ERROR Error: "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"
    Angular 7
    View_ListarUsuariosComponent_0 ListarUsuariosComponent.html:26
    Angular 24
    RxJS 5
    Angular 9
ListarUsuariosComponent.html:26:8
ERROR CONTEXT 
Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 34, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…} }
ListarUsuariosComponent.html:26:8
    View_ListarUsuariosComponent_0 ListarUsuariosComponent.html:26
    Angular 16
    RxJS 5
    Angular 9`

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient permite [convertir la respuesta a un determinado tipo](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response). En tu caso deberías crear un modelo `Usuario` y usar `http.get` tal que así:

```
getAll() {
  return this.http.get<Usuario[]>(this.url + '/all');
}
```

Estoy suponiendo que la consulta devuelve un array de usuarios.

Si lo haces así podrás también declarar el tipo en las suscripciones:

```
this.usuarioService.getAll().subscribe(
  (usuarios: Ususario[]) => {
    console.log("USUARIOS = ",usuarios);
  }
);
```

Comment: Si, supones bien. Es conveniente hacer el subscribe en el servicio para devolver directamente la coleccino de objetos ?

Comment: No, no es conveniente

Comment: El hecho que el Typescript te permita hacer static typing no significa que en runtime los objetos sean del tipo que esperas. El error que aparece es de runtime por lo que especificar un tipo no tiene nada que ver con la solución al problema

Comment: Creo que su error es porque `JSON.parse()` espera un string, y le ha dado un objeto - en su caso sin tipo porque no lo ha declarado. Edito